# Unity3D PlayerPrefs issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, save, load, local-storage, scoring

I am having an issue, when I lower the score from 10 to lets say 9 it changes the highscore anyway even though it is a lower number. Here is the code:

```
var score : int;
var highscore : int;

function Start(){
    highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore");
    score = 9;
    if(score > highscore){
        highscore = score;
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}

function OnGUI(){
    GUI.Label(Rect(10,10,100,20), score.ToString() );
    GUI.Label(Rect(10,50,100,20), highscore.ToString() );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `GetInt` but you're not using `SetInt` afterwards, so your `PlayerPrefs.Save()` call isn't actually saving anything new.

Try using `SetInt` before `Save()`:

```js
if(score > highscore){
    highscore = score;
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highscore", highscore);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```